# Smooth crossfade/transition between two videos?

Tags: transition, samsung-smart-tv

I have been successfully running the example, Creating a Video Application: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00055/index.html

What I am trying to figure out is how I can smoothly transition from one video to another using a cross fade or any other transition. In this example you are forced to call stop on the player before loading up another video causing a black flash in between.

I've tried going down the path of creating two Video instance one behind eachother and using JQuery to fade out/fade in but I am having a lot of trouble. it appears jquery fades don't even apply to the video element. Also, Is there some kind of limitation with playing two videos at the same time? Is there a better way to go about this? Would it be better to look into doing this using WebGl instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Samsung API you can play only one video at time. I can't find documentation page at the moment.

You can try different approaches:

1. use html5 `<video>` tag, maybe browser will be capable of playing 2
   of them.
2. use screenshot from second video, and fadeOut it over video
   before stopping first video and starting next.
3. you can recode your videos in 1 continious video in any video editing software. If you need to switch between videos, you can jump to position of next video start.

Comment: Realized I could use video.js last night! Unfortunately it looks like you still cannot play two of them. Looks like screenshot is the only option. Thanks!

Comment: The screenshot isn't working out so well. The colours of the video are vastly differant then the screenshot on a real tv. Looks fine in the emulator but not so good on on real thing:S Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Video is played not by browser but by mediaprocessor, and picture composited later. looks like they have different color profiles. You can fade to black/white/gray/your logo, instead of video screenshot.

Comment: Do you think I'd have more luck taking a screenshot of the video on the device using a canvas at startup? I'll probably give that a shot later today.

Comment: I don't think canvas will capture anything at all, but try it and share your results.

Comment: Plan is to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760805/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-html5-javascript-based-video-player.

I'll report back how it goes.