# Imgur gifv file doesn't load as expected using video tag

Tags: html, gif, webm, imgur

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://i.imgur.com/91S22q6.gifv" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This doesn't seem to load the video. I assume the `.gifv` is messing it up somehow when it needs to use `.webm`. When I change it to `.webm`, it still doesn't load. Is there any way to embed a `.gifv`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Iframe method:**

```html
<iframe src="https://imgur.com/91S22q6/embed" width="200" height="220" scrolling="no" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```

**HTML video method using webm:**

```html
<video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <source src="//i.imgur.com/91S22q6.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
</video>
```

I changed the source extension from .gifv to .webm, removed the controls tag, set preload to auto, added autoplay, and added loop.

Comment: Is there any way to take a 'screenshot' of the .gifv? I have a gif-to-png PHP script which captures the first frame and then the user can press a play button, otherwise they may scroll to it and view it half-way through or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760805/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-html5-javascript-based-video-player

Comment: @spencer.sm Thanks! I take it there are no arguments to add i.e. autoplay and it's not really possible to make that work in a responsive layout?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had an issue with embedding a gifv using the webm extension.  I had success replacing the "webm" extension with "mp4".  This was only for a recently uploaded file, an older file did not have any issue.

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <source src="//i.imgur.com/91S22q6.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

This imgur support page seems to indicate using mp4 rather than webm: [Sharing Posts, GIFs, GIFvs, and Images](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000524806-Sharing-Posts-GIFs-GIFvs-and-Images-)

Answer (score 1):

The 'webm' method has been discontinued now. The new method is:

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" style="max-width: 90%; height: auto;">
  <source src="https://i.imgur.com/hxcsP6x.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```