# How to save HTML5 video canvas as an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I would like to know how to save HTML5 video canvas as an image using jQuery, JavaScript or PHP

Video canvas code.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="343291949.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I want to save the preview image of above video to images folder.

Can someone tell me a way to do this? Appreciate your time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a snapshot of HTML5-JavaScript-based video player?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760805/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-html5-javascript-based-video-player)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for :  [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Also, let have a look at [this thread](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10327812-How-to-install-ffmpeg-php-to-create-thumbnails-from-videos) which is dealing with video thumbnails creation in PhP.

Comment: As far as i know you dont need FFMPEG for HTML5 MP4 videos.

Comment: What does a simple mp4 has different from a HTML5 mp4 video ?

Comment: Its the same. What i meant is HTML5 will display a poster without FFMPEG when you use the mp4 in a video tag. Simply need to capture the video canvas and save it as an image. I have seen lot of people do it but cant find on how dose it work.