# How to load Pdf file on Canvas as a image.src?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d, 2d

I am able to load image on canvas but now I want to replace the Image with pdf file.
How to load Pdf file on **Canvas** as a image.src?

Comment: Does it need to be on canvas? If you just embed it in the document, it comes with some tools that pan and zoom, but I am not sure of your purposes.

Comment: 1) I will be importing pdf file. 2) Will plot dots or circles or markers on that pdf. 3) When I will Zoom in and Zoom out pdf at that time need to zoom in and zoom out only pdf file but not the markers which i plotted on pdf. Markers need to translate on their respective positions without scaling. 3) With the mouse drag should be able to Pan that pdf file. These are the project requirements. I implemented this with Image. But I want to do this with pdf file. pdf.js will help in this told by some people. If you know any other idea about this then will be great help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with pdf.js https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Take a look at this article http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/rendering-pdf-in-html5-canvas/

Comment: Can we zoom and Pan this pdf on canvas?

Comment: I am able to Zoom and Pan Image on canvas. Similarly I want to do with pdf file. So is this possible with canvas + HTML5 + Javascript ?

Comment: Sure you can zoom on canvas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420975/html5-canvas-zooming

Comment: I am done with Image. But with pdf.js can I Zoom + pan pdf file on canvas? I am not getting any example related to pdf zoom/pan on canvas.

Comment: Whatever is drawn in the canvas (pdf or images) you can zoom and pan programmatically.