# Stream pdf or image using tokbox api

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I want to stream pdf, ppt, image file from publisher to all subscriber using tokbox api. Is it possible to do that ?

if any one know about it please share your knowledge .

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code, state a problem you have with said code.

Comment: I do not have any code, i just want to know the mechanism to do as mentioned .

@pokeybit do you know about it ? then please share what you know .

Comment: I know that you're going to need some code before you ask a 'coding' question here. I think google may have the answer you are looking for.

Comment: My question is not about the coding, it's about mechanism or methodology
and i did not write single line of code until i am clear about the things.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is if you can get the pdf, ppt or image onto an HTML Canvas then you can stream a Canvas into an OpenTok Session.
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Publish-Canvas

This is easy to do with an image, you can use the [drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) method.

It looks like it's also possible to do with a PDF with pdf.js:
[How to load Pdf file on Canvas as a image.src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489261/how-to-load-pdf-file-on-canvas-as-a-image-src)

Answer (score 0):

You can use screensharing:

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/screen-sharing/js/

It allows you to share a whole screen, or just an application window.