# How can I add div content to a new page in jspdf?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

How can I add div content to a new page in jspdf? I tried to use `<br>` and it creates a new page but I can't see the contents.

```
 <div id="printArea">
    <div style="margin: 3px 430px;">First Page</div>
    <div>Place content to Second Page</div>
  </div>
```

---

```
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            $('#wrapper_div').on("click", "#print", function () {
                doc.fromHTML($('#printArea').html(), 15, 15, {
                    'width': 170,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                });
                doc.output('datauri');
            });
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

Use:

`doc.addPage();`

This will add a new page for you and after that you can add your content.

or if you want to add new page depending on content's height check this link : [jsPDF multi page PDF with HTML renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24013355/2467940)