# Jspdf - fromHtml() - Pdf with single page

Tags: css, angularjs, pdf, jspdf, fromhtml

I have a problem when I use the fromHtml function jspdf he only writes the first page in the PDF , the rest appears as blank pages.

In older versions of the plugin do not, the problem that these versions do not have css and are not compatible with images, I need it in my project .

I am very grateful if anyone can solve or know a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.
See [jsPDF multi page PDF with HTML renderrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272933/jspdf-multi-page-pdf-with-html-renderrer) it may help you solve the problem. I am working on it now.

Comment: If you the same question was already asked an answered, better to vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Well I gave up on Jspdf, I ended up putting together a print node server using PhantomJs, it got slower but it's serving me well.