# Saving HTML as PDF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html2canvas, pdfmake

I need to be able to click a button and save a modal window as a PDF.  It needs to take the styling and all content inside the div the modal is built in.

I'm not tied to any specific library but I need to use a client-side library to to get this to work.  My project is built with ASP.NET MVC & AngularJS.

I'm using pdfMake and html2canvas.  Html2canvas is taking the div content and saving it as a canvas while pdfMake takes the canvas/image and saves it as a PDF.

This works great for my modal when there is a limited amount of data/records, usually around 15.  Anytime more records are displayed, the PDF is rendered with just blank pages.

I'm not sure how to fix this so that the PDF's are rendered/generated with all of my data.  I'm thinking it could be related to the HTML2Canvas portion and not necessarily with the data.  The code [examples](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) from the developer are multiple pages of text and render fast and correctly.  This tells me that I'm either missing some settings or there could be a comparability issue between HTML2Canvas and pdfMake.

I previously tried jsPDF and apparently it does not play well with CSS.  I could not get the exported files to save with the correct styling.

I am using AngularJS ng-click to call the JS method printHistoricalData().

Here is my code that currently saves the HTML as a PDF when there is limited data records.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="printHistoricalData()">PRINT</button>

<div id="historicalDataModal">
     <div class="modal-body">
          Modal Data Here
     </div>
</div>
```

**Angular/Javascript**

```
  function printHistoricalData() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("historicalDataModal"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            var docDefinition = {                      
                content: [
                    {
                        image: data,
                        width: 525,
                        alignment: "center"
                    }
                ],
                pageSize: "letter",
                pageOrientation: "portrait",
                styles: {
                    footer: {
                        fontSize: 8,
                        alignment: "center",
                        margin: [0, 0, 0, 80]
        }
                }
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download($scope.selectedGroup.title + ".pdf");
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

This might Help:

```
$scope.pdfExport = function () {
     html2canvas($("#Div"), {
                        onrendered: function (canvas) {
                            var doc= new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");
                            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
                            doc.addHTML(document.getElementById("Div"), function () {
                                doc.save('file.pdf');
                            });

                        }
                    });
 };
```

or you might use these lines instead of doc.addHTML:

```
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 180, 150);  // 180x150 mm @ (10,10)mm
                        doc.save('file.pdf');
```

Using the doc.addImage helped me counter this problem

UPDATE:

I found this answer on another post really helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934497/8466944