# Can I import an existing pdf file for modification with jsPdf?

Tags: jspdf

I'd like to create a pdf document from client-side data. I'm currently trying to do it with the jsPdf library. I have 17 pages with quite some text, but most of it remains the same regardless of the client-side data.
Is there a way to import an existing pdf file in jsPdf (containing all the constant stuff) and to just add some variable text on some pages with javascript ?

Comment: No, am afraid **jsPDF** does not have the option to import and work on existing PDF documents.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994326/jspdf-include-other-pdf