# html2Canvas query with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

Would be possible to define multiple elements with a single html2canvas call in order to retrieve multiple pictures to be inserted into a single PDF page?

Something like this:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#id1, #id2, #id3, #id4")).then(function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas); ...
```

Instead of:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#id1")).then(function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas); ...
```

I know that is possible to recursive call html2canvas `(for(var i=0; i<3; i++){}`, but I'm scared about the performance.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use fromHTML()...I think it will helps you....[refer the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272933/jspdf-multi-page-pdf-with-html-renderer)

Comment: you can use fromHTML()...I think it will helps you....[refer the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272933/jspdf-multi-page-pdf-with-html-renderer)