# How to generate a multipage PDF Using jsPDF using .html() method without jquery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I have a certain functionality where I have to export all tabs into the PDF, each tab in separate page. For tabs I have used react-tabs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabs).

It has one property called `forceRenderTabPanel`. While its true all the tabs will be rendered into the DOM.

I have used the jsPDF library for Exporting HTML(Tabs) to PDF.
jspdf has one method called `.HTML()`, which will take HTML renderer in its argument, I'm giving parent div into the argument.

As u can see in this example: [Link to my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/a11y-tabs-forked-rr814c?file=/src/App.js)

As you can see in exported PDF there are only one (Active Tab) is exporting, even though All 3 tabs has been rendered into the Dom, what I'm looking for is Each Tab should be exported in Separate Pages.

How do I make multipage PDF from HTML using jspdf's .HTML() method or any other method with CSS from external file? or **How Do I Add multipage inside .html() method's callback**
Can we carried out these task using another library or method? Any suggestion would be appreciable!!!

```
const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");    
doc.html(document.getElementById("Page1"), {
       callback: function (pdf) {
         pdf.addPage(
           [1500, 1500],
           "l"
         );
         pdf.html(document.getElementById("Page2"), {
           callback: function (pdf2) {
             pdf2.addPage(
               [1500, 1500],
               "l"
             );
             pdf2.html(document.getElementById("Page3"), {
               callback: function (pdf3) {
                 pdf3.save("3pageFS.pdf");
               },
               y: 1500,
             });
           },
         });
       },
```

I've tried using this way but I'm getting second and third blank pages, only First Page is visible!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsPDF multi page PDF with HTML renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272933/jspdf-multi-page-pdf-with-html-renderer)

Comment: FYI: You don't need "!" after every sentence. Also corrected uppercase/lowercase spelling for you.

Comment: Appreciated man @Peter Krebs!!

Comment: @programmers_view LOL !!!!!!!!

Comment: @Yogi Actually i don't want to Add text, I wanted to use HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a Sort of trick For my requirement of exporting multipage PDF using .HTML() method, U can use nested callback functions like these & give X, and Y Coordinates based on Page Size

```
   const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");   
   doc.html(document.getElementById("Page1"), {
      callback: function (pdf) {
        pdf.addPage("a4", "l");
        pdf.html(document.getElementById("Page2"), {
          callback: function (pdf2) {
            pdf2.addPage("a4", "l");
            pdf2.html(document.getElementById("Page3"), {
              callback: function (pdf3) {
                pdf3.save("multipage.pdf")
              },
              x: 0,
              y: 2 * pageHeight,
            });
          },
          x: 0,
          y: pageHeight,
        });
      },
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    });
```

Any Suggestions on How to make these code dynamic using for loop, based on number of Pages?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works perfectly fine, but as mentioned, is not very flexible when trying to loop over pages.
I changed that approach to use promises which works quite well:

```
    const pdfDoc = new jsPDF({ format: [585, 842] });
    const htmlPages = document.getElementById("pages")!.children;
    for (let i = 0; i < htmlPages.length; i++) {
      const htmlPage = htmlPages[i] as HTMLElement;
      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        pdfDoc.html(htmlPage as HTMLElement, { callback: resolve, y: 842 * i });
      });
      if (i < htmlPages.length - 1) {
        pdfDoc.addPage([585, 842]);
      }
    }
```