# To change the position of the rectangle when i click on the button using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using html5 canvas to create the image annotation to process the bank credit card form  i need to change the position of the rectangle when i click the *1.name button* the rectangle should be highlight to name column *2.city* to highlight the city column *3.phone* to highlight to phone column from the form please any body help me how to use the button click event in this following code.

html5

```
<div id="content"style="width:1200px; height:500px; overflow:scroll;">
    <canvas id="tool_sketch" width="1200" height="1500" style="background: url(https://www.google.co.in/search?q=credit+card+form&tbm=isch&source=iu&imgil=km2Z3X1TLDJb0M%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcRZ-BKzchgpLe1UBl4DMSEheEeI2zZegsVJSA9DS9PcoioWiNrB%253B1275%253B1650%253B9j5RPXytsQNrrM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.kimtrends.com%25252FCredit-card-authorization-form.html&sa=X&ei=rf6vUsbtIcbYrQf6zYHQCw&ved=0CEYQ9QEwAA&biw=1280&bih=642#q=credit+card+form+full+image&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=p4RgIAJnWO2cLM%3A%3BmYv6kLtFLnz3IM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fimg.docstoccdn.com%252Fthumb%252Forig%252F69555974.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.docstoc.com%252Fdocs%252F69555974%252FDiscount-Authorization-Form-Credit-Card-Authorization-Form%3B1275%3B1650) no-repeat  left top;"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("tool_sketch");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.globalAlpha = 25 / 100;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);

      function buttonClicked() {
      var c = document.getElementById("tool_sketch");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


      ctx.globalAlpha = 25 / 100;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

      // use this as the new position
     ctx.fillRect(416, 241, 625, 279);
  }
  function buttonClicked1() {
      var c = document.getElementById("tool_sketch");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      // Do what you need here
      alert('change position');


      ctx.globalAlpha = 25 / 100;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

      // use this as the new position
      ctx.fillRect(242, 359, 337, 423);
  }

 function buttonClicked2() {
          var c = document.getElementById("tool_sketch");
          var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.globalAlpha = 25 / 100;
          ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

          // use this as the new position
          ctx.fillRect(245, 394, 389, 416);
</script>

<input type="button" id="firstclick" onclick="buttonClicked()" value="name" />
<input type="button" id="secondclick" onclick="buttonClicked1()" value="address" />
<input type="button" id="thirdclick" onclick="buttonClicked2()"  value="phone" />
```

here i am fixing the image coordinates but it is not matching the exact pixel of the background image please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing in your posted code that shows "columns" or tables of any sort. If you want to figure out how to attach to the click event of the buttons, you use
`onclick = "myClickFunction()"`
More of this can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/3SzKS/

Comment: i need to function to change the position of the **red rectangle box** as i set the pixel value of the image using javascript code in button click event

Comment: OK, I think you are misunderstanding how the canvas works. You are just "drawing" onto a surface so think of this more as deleting one rectangle and drawing another.

Shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/3SzKS/1/

Comment: @user2817874 did this help you achieve what you wanted?

Comment: give me command to clear the rectangle of that position to be clear

Comment: @user2817874 did you even read the jsfiddle link?
The code is: ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500, 500); // 500 is an arbitrary amount, I wanted to clear the whole canvas so specified the width

Comment: yes i seen  that link, and i also modified it. But another query is that it is not taking the image coordinates rather than it taking screen coordinate

Comment: how can i zoom the background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420975/html5-canvas-zooming --> this should give you some pointers

Comment: how to control div scroll if i set the bottom of the image pixel to my button click even it should be focus in front with out scrolling the box

Comment: i used this code for auto scroll `var myDiv = document.getElementById('specificDiv');
myDiv.scrollTop = 0;` this code is working when it is in normal view but when i zoom the image it not working

Comment: how can i get jpeg image from the web services using javascript

Comment: please provide me some of the link for reference to understand the web service concept

Comment: The answers listed here will help get you started but I recommend you start posting new questions instead of relying on answers in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675833/is-there-any-web-service-available-to-get-image-using-ajax