# Is there any web service available to get image using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a web service,using that I call ajax and get image .Is there any web service available online with return bytes of images ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is [Place Kitten](http://placekitten.com/) ;)

Here is [sample URL](http://placekitten.com/200/300):

```
http://placekitten.com/200/300
```

(200 and 300 are dimensions of image you want).

Comment: any image just want to call ajax and get result

Comment: Sir can you please call ajax ? using this url