# Zooming and Panning an image within Canvas HTML

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, zooming, panning

I need to upload an image to a canvas and make it able to pan and zoom. I was referencing [GOK's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420975/html5-canvas-zooming), but I ran into problems when trying to use an image. Using an image was made panning disabled and zooming would just make the image flash.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If Jquery is an option for you, I'd advise to not to reinvent the wheel and to use some preexisting library, such as Jquery Zoom, which you can find here http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

The effect is pretty sleak and configurable (hover or click) and it should be easy to implement.

You might also be interested in http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples