# Javascript: How do I zoom in my Canvas so that my functions are still working?

Tags: javascript, css

*Dear* Stack**Overflow** *community*,

I'm currently working on a project. My goal is to color individual pixels in a **zoomed in** canvas.

*However when I used:*

```
canvas.body.style.width = '600px';
canvas.body.style.height= '300px';
```

*my functions* **stopped working**.

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:3px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var mouseDown = 0;

function mouseDownFunction() {
    ++mouseDown;
}

function mouseUpFunction() {
    --mouseDown;
} 

function mouseMoveFunction(e) {

    var posX = e.clientX;
    var posY = e.clientY;

    ctx.fillRect(posX - 10, posY - 10, 100, 100);
}

    c.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    mouseDownFunction();
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveFunction);
    });

    c.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    mouseUpFunction();
    this.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveFunction);
    });

    c.addEventListener("click", mouseMoveFunction);

    c.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){
    this.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveFunction);
    });

    c.addEventListener("mouseenter",function(e){
    if (mouseDown == 1) {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveFunction);
    }});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What's the best practice to zoom in and out of my canvas to allow easy access to individual pixels?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Sincerely,
JavaIsMyBae

Comment: `posX` and `posY` of course need to be adjusted for the zooming

Comment: Maybe this thread can help, I think it covers your topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420975/html5-canvas-zooming

Comment: Why do posX and posY need to be adjusted? I thought they were dependant on the mouse position(x+y).