# How to get real position of mouse when zoomable to continue drawing the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scale

I want to use the canvas for zoomable content but i impossible to do. I created zoom-In and zoom-out buttons.
How way to implement this using the canvas that pans and zooms an element?
If using "scale" , how way to get real position of mouse when zoomable to continue drawing the canvas.
Thanks.

```js
       // Variables for referencing the canvas and 2dcanvas context
        var canvas,ctx;

        // Variables to keep track of the mouse position and left-button status
        var mouseX,mouseY,moving, mouseDown=0;

        // Variables to keep track of the touch position
        var touchX,touchY;

        var userDrawnPixels = [];

        // Get the touch position relative to the top-left of the canvas
        // When we get the raw values of pageX and pageY below, they take into account the scrolling on the page
        // but not the position relative to our target div. We'll adjust them using "target.offsetLeft" and
        // "target.offsetTop" to get the correct values in relation to the top left of the canvas.
        function getTouchPos(e) {
                if (!e)
                    var e = event;

                if(e.touches) {
                    if (e.touches.length == 1) { // Only deal with one finger
                        var touch = e.touches[0]; // Get the information for finger #1
                        touchX=touch.pageX-touch.target.offsetLeft;
                        touchY=touch.pageY-touch.target.offsetTop;
                    }
                }
        }

        // Set-up the canvas and add our event handlers after the page has loaded
        function init() {
                // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document
                canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

                canvas.focus();

                canvas.width  = (window.innerWidth > 400) ? 400 : window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = (window.innerHeight > 400) ? 400 : window.innerHeight;

                // If the browser supports the canvas tag, get the 2d drawing context for this canvas
                if (canvas.getContext)
                    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Check that we have a valid context to draw on/with before adding event handlers
                if (ctx) {
                    // React to mouse events on the canvas, and mouseup on the entire document
                    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
                    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
                    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseOrTouchUp, false);

                    // React to touch events on the canvas
                    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', sketchpad_touchStart, false);
                    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', sketchpad_touchMove, false);
                    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', mouseOrTouchUp, false);
                }
        }

        // Draws a dot at a specific position on the supplied canvas name
        // Parameters are: A canvas context, the x position, the y position, the size of the dot
        function drawLine(ctx, x, y, size) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
                ctx.beginPath();

                var n = userDrawnPixels.length;
                var point = userDrawnPixels[n-1];

                if ((n>1) && moving) {
                    var prevPoint = userDrawnPixels[n-2];
                    ctx.moveTo(prevPoint[0],prevPoint[1]);
                    ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
                } else {
                    //ctx.moveTo(point[0],point[0]);
                    //ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
                }

                ctx.lineCap = "round";
                ctx.lineJoin = "round";
                ctx.lineWidth = size;
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
        }


        function drawDot(ctx, x, y, size) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";

                // Draw a filled circle
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
        }

                // Keep track of the mouse button being pressed and draw a dot at current location
        function sketchpad_mouseDown() {

                userDrawnPixels.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
                drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,3);

                mouseDown=1;
        }


        function mouseOrTouchUp() {
                mouseDown=0;
                moving=0;
        }

        function sketchpad_mouseMove(e) {
                // Update the mouse co-ordinates when moved
                getMousePos(e);

                // Draw a dot if the mouse button is currently being pressed
                if (mouseDown==1) {
                    drawLine(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,3);
                    userDrawnPixels.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
                    moving=1;
                }
        }

        // Get the current mouse position relative to the top-left of the canvas
        function getMousePos(e) {
                if (!e)
                    var e = event;

                if (e.offsetX) {
                    mouseX = e.offsetX;
                    mouseY = e.offsetY;
                }
                else if (e.layerX) {
                    mouseX = e.layerX;
                    mouseY = e.layerY;
                }
        }

        // Draw something when a touch start is detected
        function sketchpad_touchStart() {
                getTouchPos();
                userDrawnPixels.push([touchX, touchY]);
                drawDot(ctx,touchX,touchY,3);

                // Prevent a scrolling action as a result of this touchmove triggering.
                event.preventDefault();

                moving=1;
        }

        function sketchpad_touchMove(e) {
                getTouchPos(e);
                userDrawnPixels.push([touchX, touchY]);
                drawLine(ctx,touchX,touchY,3);

                // Prevent a scrolling action as a result of this touchmove triggering.
                event.preventDefault();
        }

        init();
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>HTML5 Canvas Drawing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="300" style="border:1px solid #777"></canvas>
 <br>
 <button onclick="zoomIn();">Zoom In</button>
  <button onclick="zoomOut();">Zoom Out</button>
</body>
</html>
```

‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Canvas: Zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420975/html5-canvas-zooming)